# Display ".doc" & ".docx" in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My users can upload their document and this document should be seen by other user.
 PDF & Excel document work fine but some doc & docx don't.

I've tried to use both gem ("docx" and "doc_ripper") but each one can just handle basic thing (table won't work ...).

Any possibilities to display the file?

Comment: Side note to my answer: please don't tag questions with irrelevant tags. This has nothing directly to do with Swift or Objective-C, and you haven't provided any sample code for us to advise on. Please bear this in mind in future and provide sample code where possible, showing what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd recommend looking at using WKWebView instead of UIWebView. Yes, the API is more tricky to work with, but UIWebView is deprecated, and you'll find it easier to move over now rather than have your app rejected by Apple in a future release.

If the .doc files don't need to be editable (just viewable), I'd recommend converting them to a PDF or similar doc type server-side to avoid the .doc display problems. There are libraries that can help with this, or you can script LibreOffice and OpenOffice to do this. The other option would be to use something like Google Docs and embed that in your webview. See here for more details: https://support.strikingly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206244861-Embed-Google-Docs